# Make text flow behind enum labels

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am not sure what the correct terminology is, so I will just show pictures of what I want.

This is how enumerate behaves by default:

[image: default enumerate behaviour]

And this is what I want:

[image: desired enumerate behaviour]

Sample code:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent~~~1.~ This is some dummy text to demonstrate what I want. It should flow to the left behind enumeration labels (what's the correct terminology?)

~

\noindent~~~2.~ This is also dummy text.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

with use of `enumitem` package and its optin `wide` is simple. for local settings:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
\item   This is some dummy text to demonstrate what I want. It should flow to the left behind enumeration labels (what's the correct terminology?)
\item   This is also dummy text.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and when you like to have all enumerate list on such a way:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{wide}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   This is some dummy text to demonstrate what I want. It should flow to the left behind enumeration labels (what's the correct terminology?)
\item   This is also dummy text.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

for more options and adjustment see documentation for `enumitem` package.